# Lebesgue Stieltjes measure

Tags: real-analysis

I think i have the solution to the following question, i would just like to make it sure that i am correct.

Let $F$ be a function on $\mathbb{R}$ that is bounded, continuous and strictly increasing. If $\nu _F$ is the Lebesgue Stieltjes measure, show that $m(E)=\nu_F(F^{-1}(E))$, for all Borel measurable subsets $E$ of the range of $F$. (m is the Lebesgue measure)

My argument in general lines goes like this:

Notice that the Borel subsets of the range of $F$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra generated by the semiopen subsets $(a,b]$ of the range of $F$.

$m=\nu _F$ on these sets.

Both $m$ and $\nu _F$ are $\sigma$-finite so the equality follows to all Borel subsets of the range.

Comment: We are not comparing $m$ and $\nu_F$. We are comparing $m$ and the *pushforward measure* $F_* \nu_F$. But your idea is correct; we can first show that $m((a, b]) = \nu_F(F(x) \in (a, b])$ and then the claim follows from usual monotone class argument.

Comment: @ Sangchul Lee What do you mean by monotone class argument?

Comment: I used that term in a very naive sense. If you can show that some property is satisfied for all generating sets and stable under $\sigma$-algebra operations, then this property should hold for all measurable set. In this specific case, *Dynkin's $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem* is more suited for our aim. Finally, function-space versions of this theorem are usually called [*monotone class theorem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_class_theorem). To be accurate, what I really wanted to mention was the $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem.